# String Manipulation.Find string between 2 indexes

Tags: c#, .net

Given a string eg 500 chars and I want to pick a string between index 400 and index 430.
How do you write such a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`string.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method.

Like `var truncString = longString.Substring(400, 30);`.

Note, that you should check the length of `longString` that it is at least 430 chars. If it is not, `Substring` will throw an exception.

Comment: +1 - as you entered your answer before my page had updated :)

Answer (score 4):

```
string x = "aaaa";
string part = x.Substring(400,Math.Min(x.Length,430)-400);
```

Answer (score 0):

yourstring.Substring(startindex, length)

Answer (score 0):

Substring() method of a string object will give you this.

```
string s = "your huge string .... 700 characters later";
string between = s.Substring(400, 30); //start at char 400, take 30 chars
```

Answer (score 0):

If `string S` is your 500 char string then you can:

```
string result = S.Substring(400, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not super important, just something to be aware of to avoid "off-by-one"-like errors.

Since you didn't explicitly state whether or not to include the endpoints,
`yourString.Substring(400, 30)` won't give you *only* the characters between indices 400 and 430 (i.e. *ex*cluding index 400 and 430).

Instead, what you get is the substring composed of the characters from index 400 (inclusive) to index 429 (inclusive).

To actually get the string between two indices *ex*cluding the endpoints (resulting in a string composed of the characters from indices 40*1* to 4*29*) you require something like:

```
yourString.Substring(beginIndex+1,endIndex-beginIndex-1);
```

And if you wanted to include both index 400 *and* 430 (resulting in a 31 char string):

```
yourString.Substring(beginIndex,endIndex-beginIndex+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`string result = S.Substring(startIndex, startIndex - endIndex);`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as asked, you should explain a little bit of context and possibly link out to the api documentation that you are reccomending as the answer

Answer (score 0):

c# 8 has the useful range index method on string [n..L]

- more examples on https://www.codejourney.net/csharp-8-slicing-indexes-ranges/.

```cs
var example = "An extraordinary day dawns with each new day.";
Console.WriteLine(example[3..(15+1)]);
// extraordinary
//if you use ^ then it grabs the index from the end
Console.WriteLine(example[3..^5]);
// extraordinary day dawns with each new
```

specific to question

```cs
var result = example[400..(430+1)];
```