# How can I slice a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, slice

```
string word = "hello";
```

So what I want to do is slice the string so that I can print, for example, elloh to the console window. In python it's so simple but I'm not sure if there's a specific method for slicing in c#.

Comment: `In python it's so simple` What is hard in c#?

Comment: The answer is only one or two clicks from this page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ). Learn to use the docs, it's usually quicker than asking.

Comment: Superficially everything is so easy, but then the things may get very complicated (even if you 'read the docs' where Microsoft is not a perfect example of giving answers). 
Let's take pretty trivial example, what if one wants to recognize if first character in string is unicode char where 1st char may be Unicode or ASCII? 
I know this may not be the case in this particular question (there shall be better question). 
I am just saying that 'read the doc' does not always nail it, even if things look trivial.

Comment: @ljgww There's an easy answer to the question you ask ;) : All character codepoints in dotnet are stored internally as utf-16. It's only when you render a string to bytes that the encoding is relevant.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this fact (did not know that). Just for the clarification let's state one more helpful fact here: "In C#, *string* is an alias for the String class in .NET framework."

Comment: Likely this is what you were looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx

That article references a Span<T> for dealing optimally with string slices in ways that don't generate additional allocations.

Comment: This needs to be reopened because C# 8 now allows slicing in a similar way to Python. The answer in 2022 will be different and faster

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756523/string-manipulation-find-string-between-2-indexes/74393090#74393090.

Answer (score 55):

A string can be indexed to get characters:

```
string word = "hello";
char h = word[0];
```

or strings have methods for "slicing":

```
int start = 0;
int length = 1;
string h = word.Substring(start, length);
```

Why not [read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and find out for yourself?

Comment: correct answer but not accepted as answer?

Comment: Nope I want something that will return me a ReadOnlySpan<char> which I can pass to uint.Parse without having to allocate memory, which is what substring does

Comment: @trampster Unless you're Ali Appleby, the author of the question, please don't leave comments that seems to reply to other comments. Right here now it looks like the question "... but not accepted as answer?" has a reply from you, which I doubt was the case.

Comment: It's not 2014 anymore and if you google how to slice a string, like I did because you want to use Span and Slice is the terminology that spans uses, well you get this answer. Joel and Jeff were quite clear when they made this site that they want the answers to stay relevant. Ali probably doesn't care about this question anymore but the thousands of people hitting this page from google do.

Comment: @trampster Why are you responding to 4 year old answers as if you're continuing a conversation?  They didn't post the answer for you today, yesterday, or even last year.  It was posted for Ali Appleby 4 years ago, and it was current at the time.

Comment: @CtrlS And remains current today. This is the goto way to slice strings. When you run into performance issues because you're slicing so many strings that it's a problem, then trampster's points become valid, but that's not what was asked here. Using a JCB digger to plant a seedling would be a stupid recommendation, as is worrying about memory allocation to print "olleh" to the console on any computer more recent than about 50 years old.

Comment: @spender I used this answer today to solve an issue I had requiring `Substring`, so I would have to agree!

Comment: @spender I'm just addressing the fact that there is no need for people to be "tagging" answers as obsolete based on their own needs, especially when the answer was not posted recently.

Comment: @CtrlS Joel and Jeff were quite clear when they started stack overflow, they want the questions and answers to stay relevant, if you search google and get stackoverflow as the first hit, then they want the info to be useful and not some 4 years out of date stuff that's now wrong because the terminology has changed. That's why questions and answers can be edited by people with enough reputation.

Comment: @trampster Irrelevant to *you* does not make it irrelevant.

Answer (score 11):

There's no exact translation from the concept of a slicing, but a [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is generally what you want.

It is unclear to me what your exact criteria is to slice it up, but this would do what you want:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "hello";
    var output = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 1) + input.Substring(0, 1);

    Console.WriteLine (output);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To "slice" a string, you use the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
string word = "hello";
string ordw = word.Substring(1) + word.Substring(0, 1);
```

However, a different answer would be to check out [NSlice](https://github.com/nabuk/NSlice), a library built to handle python-like slicing of arrays.

Will it make it easier to do what you asked? No. Will it make it easier to "slice" different kinds of collections? Possibly.

Comment: Nope I want something that will return me a ReadOnlySpan<char> which I can pass to uint.Parse without having to allocate memory, which is what substring does.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is from 2014, way before `ReadOnlySpan<char>` was available. At the moment this was as good as it got.

Comment: @trampster Support for `int.Parse(ReadOnlySpan<char>)` has only been implemented in .NET Core 2.1. It has not been made available for .NET Standard or .NET Framework. Since you already know about `ReadOnlySpan<char>` I am not sure why you are complaining about `Substring`, since it seems you already know what you can use. Do you have a question?

Comment: In 2022 spans and slicing could be used.

Answer (score 4):

C# 8.0 has added the `System.Range` operator, so now you can do something like this:

```
string word = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(word[1..] + word[0]);
```

Which outputs `"elloh"`

Answer (score 2):

you should use the `substring` function of string:

```
word.Substring(1);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Nope this allocates memory, so it slow.

Comment: @trampster Please don't go around flagging the whole internet as obsolete just because something better has come along afterwards. I agree that `ReadOnlySpan<char>` will provide a better alternative in some cases now but if you intend to flag every answer that tells people to use `Substring` as "not good enough" I'd hate to see you find the Cobol documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want an *extension method* like this:

```
public static string Rotate(this string s, int numberOfChars)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    return s;
  numberOfChars %= s.Length;
  if (numberOfChars == 0)
    return s;
  if (numberOfChars < 0)
    numberOfChars += s.Length;

  return s.Substring(numberOfChars) + s.Remove(numberOfChars);
}
```