# String Slicing in c# using intervals

Tags: python, c#, string, range

In python there are ways that allow you to access the string using an interval(slicing):

Example
Get the characters from position 2 to position 5 (not included):

```
b = "Hello, World!"
print(b[2:5])
```

Is there something similar in c#?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I slice a string in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928315/how-can-i-slice-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Yes, every `String` is also an `IEnumerable<char>`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Etheraex  not really, because I was looking for something similar to slicing in that link only the substring is used, I think the closest thing was the range option that I didn't know about and that was proposed in the answer to the question. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Jodrell Probably it can be solved also with take and skip, but i think range selector is clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# 8.0 (or higher) you can use *ranges*, e.g

```cs
var b = "Hello, World!";

var result = b[2..5];
```

Or on old c# versions, `Substring`:

```cs
var b = "Hello, World!";

// start from 2nd char (0-based), take 3 characters
var result = b.Substring(2, 3);
```

Finally, you can use *Linq*, but it's overshoot here:

```cs
var b = "Hello, World!";

// Skip first 2 characters, take 3 chars and concat back to the string 
var result = string.Concat(b
    .Skip(2)
    .Take(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a substring.

```
string hw = "hello world";
Console.WriteLine(hw.Substring(1,1), hw.Substring(5, 1));
```

OR convert it into a char array

```
string hw = "hello world";
var array = hw.ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(array[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From c#8 you can use ranges:

```
b = "Hello, World!"
Console.WriteLine(b[2..5]
```

This prints:

```
llo
```

The best official guide is [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes).

---

When coming from Python, you should be aware of an important difference.

In Python:

```
b = "Hello, World!"
print(b[2:15])

llo, World!
```

In C#:

```
var b = "Hello, World!";
Console.WriteLine(b[2..15]);

Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. (Parameter 'length')
```